# Should this question actually be marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicates

I have marked [Can you Contingency a spell from a Ring of Spell Storing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128082/can-you-contingency-a-spell-from-a-ring-of-spell-storing) as a duplicate of [Can Contingency be used with a spell cast from an Ioun Stone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124689/can-contingency-be-used-with-a-spell-cast-from-an-ioun-stone), but there was some disagreement in chat as to the validity of that decision.

The main reason for my closure is that the wording of the two magic items at the heart (as I perceive it) of the questions ([Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing) and [Reserve Ioun Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ioun-stone)) have virtually identical wording. This, in my mind, makes the questions mechanically identical. However, they are still different items in name which makes them technically different questions and not exactly the same question.

So, in my never-ending quest to understand the way that we use duplicate closure as a tool I pose the question to you all.

**Should these questions be marked as duplicates?**

(Given the direction this seems to be going I have reopened the Question. Better to have a duplicate be answered and active and close it later than to unjustly close a question that shouldn't be.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe these shouldn't be marked as duplicates because, as you say, they are about two different items. My understanding of the way duplicates work is that broadly, it is the questions that have to be the same rather than the answers. In this case, the questions are clearly about two different things that just happen to work in almost the same way.

Comment: I agreed, and have voted to reopen the question. They should certainly be linked, but they're not duplicates.

Comment: I agree. A visitor trying to find out how this works with a ring of spell storing would not care how an ioun stone would work, it's not the item they're using. They'd be very confused by the closure, not be sure why an ioun stone is relevant, and leave to continue digging through other google search results.

Comment: @doppelgreener I like this way of looking at it and I will remember this as a way to help sort it out next time I have this debate.